# List of values in json file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file that looks like this (shortened):

```json
data = {
    "station": [
        {
            "key": "105285",
            "name": "Borlänge Sol",
            "owner": "SMHI",
            "ownerCategory": "CLIMATE",
            "measuringStations": "CORE",
            "from": 536457600000,
            "to": 1664719200000,
            "height": 168.0,
            "latitude": 60.4878,
            "longitude": 15.4297,
            "value": [{"date": 1664719200000, "value": "0", "quality": "Y"}],
        },
        {
            "key": "71415",
            "name": "Göteborg Sol",
            "owner": "SMHI",
            "ownerCategory": "CLIMATE",
            "measuringStations": "CORE",
            "from": 1286409600000,
            "to": 1664719200000,
            "height": 84.824,
            "latitude": 57.6879,
            "longitude": 11.9796,
            "value": [{"date": 1664719200000, "value": "1429", "quality": "Y"}],
        },
        {
            "key": "68545",
            "name": "Hoburg Sol",
            "owner": "SMHI",
            "ownerCategory": "CLIMATE",
            "measuringStations": "CORE",
            "from": 1352991600000,
            "to": 1664719200000,
            "height": 36.0,
            "latitude": 56.921,
            "longitude": 18.1506,
            "value": [{"date": 1664719200000, "value": "0", "quality": "Y"}],
        },
        {
            "key": "65075",
            "name": "Karlskrona Sol",
            "owner": "SMHI",
            "ownerCategory": "CLIMATE",
            "measuringStations": "CORE",
            "from": 1246406400000,
            "to": 1664719200000,
            "height": 10.0,
            "latitude": 56.1091,
            "longitude": 15.587,
            "value": [{"date": 1664719200000, "value": "3586", "quality": "Y"}],
        },
        {
            "key": "178985",
            "name": "Tarfala Sol",
            "owner": "SMHI",
            "ownerCategory": "CLIMATE",
            "measuringStations": "CORE",
            "from": 1167609600000,
            "to": 1664719200000,
            "height": 1144.0,
            "latitude": 67.9123,
            "longitude": 18.6101,
            "value": None,
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to make a list of the values which are inside `'value'`, i.e `[0, 1429, 0, 3586]`,
I tried this but it's returning an error:

```py
value_dict = [data['station'][i]['value']['value'] for i in range(len(data['station'])) if data['station'][i]['value'][0]['value'] is not None]
```

How can I access those values? Also is this the right way to ignore NoneType values (such as the last one)?

Comment: You didn't notice that the first `value` is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary, you need to index it. `['value'][0]['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values like this:

```
In [1]: [item.get('value')[0].get('value') for item in data['station']]
Out[1]: ['0', '1429', '0', '3586']
```

You can use `filter` to ignore the `None` values.

```
list(filter(None, [item.get('value')[0].get('value') for item in data['station']]))
```

Answer (score 1):

if `value` contains only one element

```
value_dict = [data['station'][i]['value'][0]['value'] for i in range(len(data['station']))]
```

or if contains more than 1

```
value_dict = [[data['station'][i]['value'][j]['value'] for j in range(len(data['station'][i]['value']))] for i in range(len(data['station']))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `"station"` key first and iterate through the list of dictionaries. Get the `"value"` key and check if it's not `None`. Then it should be a list of single dictionary. Get it's item and then it's `"value"` key:

```py
result = []
for d in data["station"]:
    value = d["value"]
    if value is not None:
        result.append(value[0]["value"])
print(result)
```